# Button on first Item of ListView enables answers of 4th, 7th, 10th listView items also

Tags: android, listview, adapter

This code is for a `ListView` that gives Question and their answers in every list item. I have added a button to *SHOW ANSWER*. As I click on *SHOW ANSWER* of first item, it shows the answer of first item, 4th item, 7th item, 10th item & so on.

My `Aptitude.java`

```
public class Aptitude extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = Aptitude.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    boolean first = true;

    // URL to get questions
    private int offset = 0;
    private int limit = 10;
    private int faq = 2;

    private String url = "xyz/gk_app/qa.php/?faq="+ faq + "&offset=" + offset + "&limit=" + limit;

    String ques, optn_a, optn_b, optn_c, optn_d, correct_optn;

    View loading_footer;
    private int preLast;
    Boolean flag = false;

    Aptitude_Custom_Adapter adapter;

    private ArrayList<String> array_questions = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> array_correct_answer = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aptitude);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_aptitude);

        loading_footer = lv.inflate(Aptitude.this, R.layout.loading_footer, null);
        lv.removeFooterView(loading_footer);

        new GetQuestions().execute();

        lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

                if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                    if(preLast!=lastItem && flag == true) {
                        lv.addFooterView(loading_footer);
                        flag = false;
                        new GetQuestions().execute();
                        preLast=lastItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    private class GetQuestions extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Aptitude.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Loading question");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    JSONArray questions = jsonObj.getJSONArray("questions");
                    url = jsonObj.getString("next_url");

                    // looping
                    for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);

                        ques = c.getString("questions");
                        optn_a = c.getString("optn_a");
                        optn_b = c.getString("optn_b");
                        optn_c = c.getString("optn_c");
                        optn_d = c.getString("optn_d");
                        correct_optn = c.getString("correct_answer");

                        array_questions.add(ques);
                        array_correct_answer.add(chooseCorrectAnswer(optn_a, optn_b, optn_c, optn_d, correct_optn));
                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

            if(first == true) {
                adapter = new Aptitude_Custom_Adapter(array_questions, array_correct_answer, getApplicationContext());
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                first = false;
            } else {
                int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                adapter.add(array_questions, array_correct_answer);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

          //      Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
          //      adapter = new Aptitude_Custom_Adapter(array_questions, array_correct_answer, getApplicationContext());
          //      lv.setAdapter(adapter);
          //      Setting new scroll position
                lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

            }
            lv.removeFooterView(loading_footer);
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    private String chooseCorrectAnswer( final String optn_a, final String optn_b, final String optn_c, final String optn_d, final String correct_optn) {
        String correct_answer = null;
        if(correct_optn.equals("optn_a")){
            correct_answer = optn_a;
        } if(correct_optn.equals("optn_b")){
            correct_answer = optn_b;
        } if(correct_optn.equals("optn_c")){
            correct_answer = optn_c;
        } if(correct_optn.equals("optn_d")){
            correct_answer = optn_d;
        }
        return correct_answer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Aptitude.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        array_questions.removeAll(array_questions);
        array_correct_answer.removeAll(array_correct_answer);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; goto parent activity.
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And the adapter `Aptitude_Custom_Adapter.java`

```
public class Aptitude_Custom_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public Resources res;;
    private ArrayList<String> questionlist, correct_ans;

    public Aptitude_Custom_Adapter(ArrayList<String> q, ArrayList<String> c, Context a) {
        activity =  a;
        questionlist=q;
        correct_ans=c;
        System.out.println("in const: " + questionlist.size());
    }

    public void add(ArrayList<String> q, ArrayList<String> c){
        questionlist.addAll(q);
        correct_ans.addAll(c);
        System.out.println("in add: " + questionlist.size());
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(questionlist.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return questionlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView ques_no, text_ques, text_ans;
        public Button btn_ansr_show_hide;
        public Boolean flag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aptitude_list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ques_no = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ttp_ques_no);
            holder.text_ques = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ttp_question);
            holder.text_ans = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ttp_answer);
            holder.btn_ansr_show_hide = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_ansr_show_hide);

            vi.setTag( holder );

        } else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(questionlist.size()<=0){
            holder.text_ques.setText("No Data");
            holder.text_ans.setText("No Data");
            holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setText("");
        } else {
            holder.ques_no.setText("Question No. " + String.valueOf(position+1));
            holder.text_ques.setText(questionlist.get(position).concat("?"));

            holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        System.out.println("Position: "+position);
                        holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (correct_ans.get(position).length() > 30){
                            holder.text_ans.setText(correct_ans.get(position).concat("."));
                        } else {
                            holder.text_ans.setText(correct_ans.get(position));
                        }
                        holder.flag = false;
                    }
            });

            if (holder.flag == false){
                if (correct_ans.get(position).length() > 30){
                    holder.text_ans.setText(correct_ans.get(position).concat("."));
                } else {
                    holder.text_ans.setText(correct_ans.get(position));
                }
            }
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

The main layout `activity_aptitude.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".Aptitude">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Aptitude Questions"
                android:id="@+id/to_aptitude"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ff6b6b"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView_aptitude"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the list item layout `aptitude_list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:background="#ffffff">


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/layout_question">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Question: "
                    android:id="@+id/tv_ttp_ques_no"
                    android:textColor="#4a46c1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="This is a Sample question. This is a Sample question. This is a Sample question. This is a Sample question. "
                    android:id="@+id/tv_ttp_question"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#272727" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/layout_answer">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Answer: "
                    android:id="@+id/tv_answer"
                    android:textColor="#4a46c1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text=""
                        android:id="@+id/tv_ttp_answer"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="#272727" />

                    <Button
                        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Show Answer"
                        android:id="@+id/btn_ansr_show_hide"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class named `Question` like this.

```
public class Question {
    public String question; 
    public boolean answerShowed = false; // Make the attribute false by default

    // Add a constructor
    public void Question(String question, boolean answerShowed) {
        this.question = question;
        this. answerShowed = answerShowed;
    }
}
```

Now take the `ArrayList` like

```
private ArrayList<String> array_questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

And while adding questions in the `ArrayList`

```
ques = c.getString("questions");
Question q = new Question(ques, false); 
array_questions.add(q);  // Add the object
```

Now you need to modify your adapter a bit. At first, the constructor of your adapter should take the `ArrayList` of `Question` object now.

```
private ArrayList<Question> questionlist;

public Aptitude_Custom_Adapter(ArrayList<Question> q, ArrayList<String> c, Context a) {
    activity =  a;
    questionlist = q;
    correct_ans = c;
    System.out.println("in const: " + questionlist.size());
}
```

Now you need to modify your `getView` and other functions accordingly. Get the question string from `questionlist.get(position).question`.

The tricky part you've missed in your adapter is to set the visibility outside of your `holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setOnClickListener` function. And the other thing is, you need to provide both `if-else` condition for showing or disappearing the *SHOW ANSWER* button.

So your `getView` function should look something like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aptitude_list_item, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ques_no = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ttp_ques_no);
        holder.text_ques = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ttp_question);
        holder.text_ans = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_ttp_answer);
        holder.btn_ansr_show_hide = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_ansr_show_hide);

        vi.setTag( holder );
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    holder.ques_no.setText("Question No. " + String.valueOf(position + 1));
    holder.text_ques.setText(questionlist.get(position).question.concat("?"));

    if (questionlist.get(position).answerShowed) {
        holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.text_ans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (correct_ans.get(position).length() > 30) holder.text_ans.setText(correct_ans.get(position).concat("."));
        else holder.text_ans.setText(correct_ans.get(position));

    } else {
        holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.text_ans.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.btn_ansr_show_hide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!questionlist.get(position).answerShowed)
                questionlist.get(position).answerShowed = true; 

            // Call notifyDataSetChanged here
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: it is returning multiple data, 10, 36, 72 & so on..i have only 18 questions.